# Why is there such a push for client side frameworks nowadays?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, django, angularjs, mvvm

*Hopefully this question is not off topic, personally I feel like this is a perfectly valid programming question that I have as a programmer looking towards the future.*

Guys, I'm failing to understand why I want to involve my websites with client side frameworks like Angular, Backbone, Ember, React, this, that or the other.

The fact of the matter is why learn something like Angular when they're pretty much pulling the rug out from under people and companies who've invested millions into Angular 1.0 in order to make a new framework which they will call angular 2.0?

If I want some basic dom manipulation why learn a framework at all.  For instance, on the home page of my movies site [www.noobmovies.com](http://www.noobmovies.com)  you'll notice some pagination, this is entirely done by grabbing JSON passed back from a Django Server View and using the client to parse the Data.  Say I need to update a movie etc... why not just pass some data via Ajax and send the response back?

The bottom line is much of what AngularJS and the like does, aims to replace mature frameworks like Django, Ruby on Rails etc... but why make life harder at the moment to jump on these buzzword projects that don't seem to do anything more than what these entrenched frameworks are more than capable of doing at the present?

To me, I've played with React, Angular and Backbone.  I don't like having to learn an entire framework to do something I may be better off doing myself.   It seems like all of these client side frameworks are not production ready to begin with, change way to frequently and make things harder than they need to be for many mundane tasks.

To me it just seems like everybody coming out of school is like, Dude, I have to build something with Angular to like keep up with the in crowd.  I see no reason why Angular projects are any better than Django or Ruby on Rails, in fact for the most part I see many cases of them being worse.

Comment: You should ask your question [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).
Angularjs is great to build dynamic single page application and it allows to clearly separate your models from your views. Moreoever it's much more testable

Comment: Both of the architectures (rich client, rich server) have up- and downsides. But scaling is the key factor, why not just let the browser do the expensive operations?

Comment: I'm voting this as "Primarily Opinion Based" because it is far too emotionally charged to get any clear answers, and probably beyond the scope of what SO as a medium can provide. You clearly have an opinion formed and are looking for validation of that opinion, not an actual debate about the merits of client side frameworks.

Comment: Why do you think that client side frameworks can replace server side frameworks? The only thing they have in common is a flavor of MVC. Other than that, they solve totally different problems. Also if you find value in developing a web app with Django or Rails, how can you not see the value in a client side framework? The short answer is that frameworks, client or server side, solve common architecture & technology problems found in web development. With that said, you're not obliged to use these tools. Instead you can solve the problems yourself. Sometimes that can be a good thing.

Comment: All great comments.  I appreciate them.  Last Night, I read about how the Angular community might be fragmented by Angular 2.0.  I then read a bunch about JSX and why React uses it.  Then I tried to use React but found the documentation to be frustrating especially without the use of JSX.

Ultimately, I was looking for some tool that I thought would be helpful to create interactive content on a pretty typical website.  I think I just became fed up with my lack of progress after several weeks of playing with this or that.  (only in spare time, not like I spent actual weeks etc..)

Comment: The funny thing about Angular 2.0 is how they drop support for IE10+. Meaning if you are writing a software applications for internal use by customers you will need to wait till none of your customers are still on IE10. Right now it is a struggle, at least for us, to get our customers off of IE8. So when I look at the radical changes coming in Angular 2.0 my thoughts are, thank god our client / server code can be iterated separately and it will probably be 2-3 years before we even assess using it.

Comment: @FredericLeFeurmou [Please stop using Programmers.se as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl).  [programmers.se] is for whiteboard development questions.  Speculative conversations like this one are off topic most everywhere on the SE network *except for chat*.

Comment: Also 1. can't create complex webapps relying on server side rendering only 2. pushing work to the client makes servers cheaper 3. proper use of good client side frameworks makes development easier 4. screw fads, use what works for your situ, save the rest for when they are needed.  Done and done.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments, of the question, what client / server architectures to use should be considered on a case by case basis and will always have so e kind of personal bias to it.

I cannot speak to the push for client framework as a whole by at my place of business there was a push for client framework for the simple yet important reason of having a clearly defined separation of client and server responsabilities. The server is responsible for only responding to client requests and sending raw data, In our case we use REST. The client is then only responsible for presenting the data to the user.

The power of doing this is because in 5 years or so when the next big client framework comes out that we choose to use not a single line of code would need to be changed on the server side.

To personal preference though I love angular because of the clear seperation the code that handles the DOM manipulation and how clean it is to use HTML to run the directives. Even with the additional Angular markup in the DOM you know exactly what will be rendered.